# Не загружается изображение на сайт - html. Spring Boot

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Почему не загружается изображение на сайт?
Использую *Spring Boot.*

Нужно ли какой-то дополнительный конфиг прописывать?

Полный путь к файлу:

```
file:///D:/DYPLOM%20PROJECT/src/main/resources/static/slov.png
```

и при переходе по этому пути в браузере изображение подгружается.

Пробовал разные варианты, ни один не работает...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Точно что-то с путем, но непонятно без разметки. попробуйте ./static/slov.png или static/slov.png

Comment: Ваша файловая система тут не причём . Вы зарускаете вебсайт и Spring boot по умолчанию откроет доступ к вашим статическим ресурсам . Все ресурсы должны быть доступны под application context. Чтобы доступиться до ресурса используйте [Thymeleaf Link URL](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls), как то так...`<img th:src="@{/slov.png}">` ну или просто уберите `static` ... `<img src="/slov.png">`